# How to continuously tail remote files using ansible?

Tags: ansible, tail

How is it possible to tail a file located at several remote servers in a known location using ansible? This question is based on this comment on this [Hacker News thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9089871):

> In my company, we have hundred machines and tailing done with ansible.
>   If we want customize the log view, we can simply edit the playbook. I
>   think it is very handy compared to we need additional npm package (and
>   not to mention additional effort for customization).

Comment: Ansible just runs ssh commands, so I imagine having a shell command running tail over the hosts in your inventory file would work. I'll let someone answer with an official response, though

Comment: This is a fundamentally wrong approach. You are using a shovel to paint your walls. While you might be able to cobble something together using Ansible, it's not the right tool for this job. You should be using a log aggregation/centralized logging system.

Comment: Sure, the proper way would indeed be to spend time on a log aggregation/centralized logging system. However, I am looking for a quick and dirty solution to tail logs from multiple servers without having to set up multiple terminal panes where each pane is tailing the logs from a single remote server.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ansible [ad-hoc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_adhoc.html) :

```
 ansible atlanta -a "tail /homedir/myfile" -f 10
```

**UPDATE**

Ansible can only print the output after completing the command. That's why I think what you want is not possible, ansible is probably not the tool you want for this job. Check issue [4870](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4870) and [3887](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3887).

If you  really want to use ansible to do this, there is [hack](http://rferrer.me/articles/live-ansible-stdout.html) posted in one of issues (haven't tested and actually I don't recommend it).

I really don't know what the guy from HN was talking about, maybe just `tail` (without the `-f`)?

Comment: I need to continuously monitor the logs using "tail -f"

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used [capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/#) to build [tasks that would tail and follow logs on multiple hosts](http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2013/12/tailing-log-files-with-capistrano-3/) and output interactively.  If you're okay with Ruby, I know this will work.  If you want to stick with Python, [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) is your thing and see [other people have done this](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/01/15/fabric-tailing-log-files-on-multiple-machines/) with it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [daggy](https://daggy.dev) for streaming commands via ssh, including `tail -f`